# issue with sendmail & html format in body

Tags: shell, sendmail

I need to send mail in unix with 2 attachments and the subject in html format.

i did the following, it helps in getting the attachment but not the body content in the mail

```
#!/bin/bash
from="b@b.com"
to="A@A.com"
subject="Status"
boundary="ZZ_/afg6432dfgkl.94531q"
body="mail_body.txt"
attachments=( "FiC.txt" "FiE.txt")

# Build headers
{

printf '%s\n' "From: $from
To: $to
Subject: $subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--${boundary}
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

cat $body
"

for file in "${attachments[@]}"; do

  [ ! -f "$file" ] && echo "Warning: attachment $file not found, skipping" >&2 && continue

 #mimetype=$(get_mimetype "$file") 

  printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"
"

  base64 "$file"
  echo
done

printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}--"

} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -oi
```

mail_body.txt's contents:

```
   echo "<html>
        <head>
        <title> Status</title>
        </head>
        "
```

Can help in getting html content printed in body part of mail?

Comment: Your described output doesn't match the actual result of running that script. Replace `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -oi` with `nl` and try it yourself

Comment: what does nl stand for

Comment: `man nl` and read up on it

Comment: i dont want to number the lines in output. thnaks

Comment: Sigh. I know you don't want to number the lines. I'm trying to get you to look at the output so you can see what's wrong. This is a fundamental method for debugging - split the problem into smaller parts. In this case I'm discarding the "send the email" part to demonstrate my [first comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577125/issue-with-sendmail-html-format-in-body?noredirect=1#comment1073709_577125).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> printf '%s\n' "…
> cat $body
> "
> ```

This *prints* the `cat` command. It does not *run* it.

And if you are going to use `\n` in the format specification, you might as well not use quoted newlines and a single massive string.

> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"
> ```

Fairly obviously, a body part designated `text/plain` will not be interpreted as `text/html`.  Although the contents of that file, as given, are not HTML in the first place.

Comment: i am sorry, i didnt get the solution